# Reset BIOS of Asus PRO5DIP

Tags: bios

When I start my Asus PRO5DIP notebook, nothing is displayed on the screen. I guess that has something to do with changes in the BIOS, since last time I've entered the BIOS and made some changes, like boot device order et cetera. So, I thought, maybe if I replace or reinsert the CMOS battery or move the jumper on the motherboard, the BIOS is reset, allowing the screen to display anything.

But I cannot find a jumper or a CMOS battery. Where on the motherboard are those located, if applicable? If not, how can I reset thw BIOS?

Comment: You will have to have to service manual to the device in order to locate it.

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah, but where can I get that. I've looked on the Asus website, but didn't find it. Plus I never received a manual mentioning the BIOS.

Comment: There literally has to be a batter, it might not be user serviceable, but it exists.